# Computing six dot products involving one common input vector

Tags: performance, simulink

I have created a Matlab Simulink model with a series of [dot products](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/dotproduct.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

[image: Simulink]

Embedded Coder generates a for loop for each dot product, as evidenced by this excerpt of the generated output:

> ```
> /* DotProduct: '<S3>/Dot Product1' incorporates:
>  *  Inport: '<Root>/LngPwr'
>  */
> EPAR_SPAF_dot_B.DotProduct1 = 0.0F;
> for (temp_ = 0; temp_ < 24; temp_++) {
>   EPAR_SPAF_dot_B.DotProduct1 += temp_DataTypeConversion[temp_] *
>   LngPwr[temp_];
> }
> /* End of DotProduct: '<S3>/Dot Product1' */
>
> /* DotProduct: '<S3>/Dot Product2' incorporates:
>  *  Inport: '<Root>/ShrtPwr'
>  */
> EPAR_SPAF_dot_B.DotProduct2 = 0.0F;
> for (temp_ = 0; temp_ < 24; temp_++) {
>   EPAR_SPAF_dot_B.DotProduct2 += temp_DataTypeConversion[temp_] *
>   ShrtPwr[temp_];
>  }
> /* End of DotProduct: '<S3>/Dot Product2' */
> ```

Can I improve the Simulink model such that it will compile to better code?

I want to avoid using embedded matlab or a S-function for the purposes of maintainability.

Comment: I find this kind of downvoting to be extremely frustrating because it communicates to me that there is a total lack of understanding of how MATLAB Simulink and Embedded Coder works.  There *IS* Working code in the original post, it just happens to be graphical.  The C-Code is auto generated.

The question is identical to any kind of other Code efficiency question since the way you craft the simulink will directly affects the C-Code generated which in turns  affects how it runs on the target.

Comment: @MichaelCoury Stackoverflow has the tag matlab, why don't you try it there? There's also http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Programmer400,  Thanks for the constructive feedback, I'll see what the Stackoverflow community looks like.  Having said that, CodeReview also has a matlab tag, so... I still pretty confident that this question falls into the realm of CodeReview **IF** the scope of CodeReview includes optimization.  I am going to continue this conversation in the meta section....

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6766/9357).

Answer (score 5):

There is a common mathematical operation involving many dot products: it's called matrix multiplication.

$$ \left[\begin{matrix}v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_4\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \\
a_4 & b_4 & c_4
\end{matrix}\right] =
\left[\begin{matrix}(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{a}) & (\vec{v}\cdot\vec{b}) & (\vec{v}\cdot\vec{c})\end{matrix}\right]
$$

So, I recommend that you [concatenate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/vectorconcatenate.html) vectors \$\color{lightgreen}1\$ to \$\color{lightgreen}6\$ into a matrix and perform matrix multiplication.

[image: Illustrated matrix multiplication]

You can also transpose and swap the matrices:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ v_4\end{matrix}\right]
 =
\left[\begin{matrix}\vec{a}\cdot\vec{v} \\ \vec{b}\cdot\vec{v} \\ \vec{c}\cdot\vec{v}\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Comment: Gosh, I wish I was better at linear algebra... I'll put this into Simulink and Embedded Coder and see what the output looks like...